# Wireguard tunnel source to c#.Net: Service Run troubleshooting

Tags: c#, windows, console-application, wireguard

I'm trying to make a simple console app client (starter.exe) on c# .NET Framework 4.6 to make a WireGuard protocol based connection using Wireguard source code.

**What is done:**

- Downloaded wireguard source code from here: *git://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-windows*
- Successfuly built Tunnel.dll in *..\embeddable-dll-service\amd64\tunnel.dll* via build.bat
- Created a project in Visual Studio 2015.using the c# code from *..\embeddable-dll-service\csharp*

**Starting from here some strange thing are happenning:**

- if launching starter.exe \service <path to *.conf> I receive the
  error

> Service run error: The service process could not connect to the
> service controller.

- if launching starter.exe without parameters everything works fine until I remove the *if{}* block:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The service
> did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion
> at WireGuardTunnel.Service.Add(String configFile) in
> D:\Depository\BitBucket\WireGuard_Tunnel_Repository\WireGuardTunnel_proj\Launcher\Service.cs:line
> 69    at WireGuardTunnel.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> D:\Depository\BitBucket\WireGuard_Tunnel_Repository\WireGuardTunnel_proj\Launcher\Program.cs:line
> 83

That means even if the code in if{} block is not executed it influencese somehow the application behaviour.

- Next, as I want to make my app work with parameters I solved the
  issue by removing return afer Service.Run and passing args[1] to Service.Add(args[1]). It works OK, but I have an extra log line (the first one due to Service.Run perpetual error described above) in the log:

> Service run error: The service process could not connect to the
> service controller.
>   235660: [TUN] [chicago4] Watching network
> interfaces
>   245661: [TUN] [chicago4] Resolving DNS names
> 245661: [TUN] [chicago4] Creating Wintun interface
>   225660: [TUN]
> [chicago4] Starting WireGuard/0.3.1 (Windows 6.1.7601; amd64)

So finally the questions:

1. Why Service.Run(confFile) does not work
2. Why Service.Run(confFile) influences the Service.Add(confFile)
3. Why if{} block is executed when I launch starte.exe with no parameters

The original Program.cs without modification:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Tunnel
{
    class Program
    {

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(SetConsoleCtrlEventHandler handler, bool add);
        private delegate bool SetConsoleCtrlEventHandler(UInt32 signal);

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string baseDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
            string configFile = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, "demobox.conf");
            string logFile = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, "log.bin");

            if (args.Length == 2 && args[0] == "/service")
            {
                configFile = args[1];
                Service.Run(configFile);
                return;
            }

            try { File.Delete(logFile); } catch { }
            Ringlogger log = new Ringlogger(logFile, "GUI");

            var logPrintingThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                var cursor = Ringlogger.CursorAll;
                while (Thread.CurrentThread.IsAlive)
                {
                    var lines = log.FollowFromCursor(ref cursor);
                    foreach (var line in lines)
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    Thread.Sleep(300);
                }
            });

            logPrintingThread.Start();

            SetConsoleCtrlHandler(delegate
            {
                Service.Remove(configFile);
                Environment.Exit(0);
                return true;
            }, true);

            try
            {
                Service.Add(configFile);
                logPrintingThread.Join();
            }
            finally
            {
                Service.Remove(configFile);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How were you able to build the DLL? I am unable to do so in the latest commit.

Comment: Any update on this? 

How did you achieve this? Is there any opensource code of yours where I can take a look at it? Can you please help me? 

@https://stackoverflow.com/users/1532494/kirpi4

Comment: @Macindows unfortunately I didn't try to build on commits after 03 december 2020.

Comment: @SANDEEPMACHIRAJU well my code is working but I still don't have the answer to my question. I've just used the logic as it is. Unformtunately I cannot share the final code - it's too huge and it's for corporate purpose but I can certainly say that the sources provided in WireGuard_Repository\embeddable-dll-service\ are enought to make it work even if it works not hoa I am expecting.

Comment: Thanks for the response kirpi4

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party but I was having the exact same issue as above and discovered that in order to get everything working correctly you have to have `Tunnel.Service.Run("path to config")` defined on application initialization either in your main loop or your constructor then you can run `Tunnel.Service.Add("path to config", true)` which will create the service and start the VPN connection. It's also good practice to destroy the service on close using `Tunnel.Service.Remove("path to config", true)` as the service will continue to run and you will still be connected to your VPN until it is stopped manually.